# 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

My code is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Mesas (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Mesa CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Dispobilidad BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT True,
    Cantidad_Asientos TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 4
);

CREATE TABLE Reservacion (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    A_Nombre_de VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    Cantidad_Personas TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    Horario TIME NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "perenganito@gmail.com"
);

CREATE TABLE HorarioMesaManager (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Horario TIME NOT NULL,
    Mesa CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Mesa) REFERENCES Mesas (Mesa) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Horario) REFERENCES Reservacion (Horario) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE ReservacionMesaManager (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Mesa CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    A_Nombre_de VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Mesas_a_Ocupar TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (A_Nombre_de) REFERENCES Reservacion(A_Nombre_de) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Mesa) REFERENCES Mesas(Mesa) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

But I'm having the following error for the table "HorarioMesaManager":

> 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index
> for constraint 'horariomesamanager_ibfk_1' in the referenced table
> 'mesas'

And for the table "ReservacionMesaManager":

> 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index
> for constraint 'reservacionmesamanager_ibfk_1' in the referenced table
> 'reservacion'

And I don't exactly why. Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error: Missing index for constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443661/mysql-error-missing-index-for-constraint)

Comment: Yes! It solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Consider this foreign key definition:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Mesa) REFERENCES Mesas (Mesa) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

Logically, the foreign key should be to a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` -- and preferably the latter.  MySQL *does* allow foreign keys to any indexed column, but I don't recommend using that "feature" (which is not supported in other databases).

The primary key is `ID`.  So your declaration should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE HorarioMesaManager (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Horario TIME NOT NULL,
    MesaId INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (MesaId) REFERENCES Mesas (ID) ON DELETE CASCADELETE CASCADE
);
```

And so on for the other foreign key references.